# How exectue MySQL multi query, in the asp classic?

Tags: mysql, asp-classic, odbc

asp --> odbc --> mysql, multi query problem.

`dbCon.execute("update wp_posts set post_abc = '1234' where ID=1602';");`: no problem

`dbCon.execute("set @aa=1602;update wp_posts set post_abc = '1234' where ID=@aa;");`: error

err message:

> [MySQL][ODBC 5.2(w) Driver][mysqld-5.1.45p1-log]You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'update wp_posts........

How can I fix this? SOS!!!

Dislikes answers:

```
dbCon.execute("set @aa=1602;");
dbCon.execute("update wp_posts set post_abc = '1234' where ID=@aa;");
```

Answer (score 6):

Add `MULTI_STATEMENTS=1` in the connection-string, or enable multiple queries in the DSN entry by going to

> Details -> Connection -> Allow multiple statements

Comment: MULTI_STATEMENTS=1 : good! good! good! good! good! good! good! thank-U! thank-U! thank-U! thank-U! thank-U! thank-U! thank-U! thank-U!^^